# Cannot access realm fetched data

Tags: ios, swift, realm, objectmapper

I successfully fetch my *Board* data via

```
let boards: [Board] = try! db.fetch(FetchRequest<Board>())
```

After that i iterate over *boards* an make a

```
print(board)
```

wich outputs:

```
Board {
    id = 1;
    name = The Name;
    shortDescription = The Description;
    slug = the_name;
}
```

But when i want to access the *board* name directly with e.g.

```
 board.name
```

the following Error is thrown:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What´s my mistake?
If *board* is not an Object, how i can achieve that it will be one?

I´m using:

```
SugarRecord
ObjectMapper 
RealmSwift
ObjectMapper_Realm
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through the missing Documentation in ObjectMapper_Realm i didn´t had the

```
 dynamic
```

keyword in front of my var declaration.

Comment: but you are also creating an array [Board] but treating it like an instance in board.name how did that work for you

Comment: I Iterate over boards. Had typo in first version, switched "board" to "boards".